# Flutter native splash screen image problem

Tags: android, flutter, cross-platform, flutter-design

I'm using the flutter native splash screen package for customizing the default splash in my flutter splash screen. I added an image to the splash screen, but the image doesn't fit properly.

My current splash screen looks like this:

[image: current splash screen]

What I want to achieve:

[image: desired splash screen]

This is my `pubspec` file:

```
# flutter_native_splash-development.yaml
flutter_native_splash:
color: "#ffffff"
image: assets/icons/splash_icon.png
color_dark: "#121212"
image_dark:
fill: true
assets/icons/splash_icon.png

android_12:
    image: assets/icons/splash_icon.png
    image_dark: assets/icons/splash_icon.png
```

Comment: show the flutter code and what you have tried?.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the details in the [Android 12+](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash#android-12-support) section of the readme.  The splash image needs blank padding within the image as per Android 12+ Splash API requirements.